# Display only the childrens from a specific category ID or slug

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

maybe someone can help me with this

I have this code by now, it displays all the categories with thumbnail that have been attributed to a post inside the loop

```
<?php foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What adjustments do i have to make to the code to display only the childrens from a specific category ID or slug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID or the slug of the category, one of these should do the trick.

Specific slug:

```
<?php 
$desired_cat_slug = 'yourslug';
foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : 
if($cat->slug == $desired_cat_slug) :
?>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
<?php 
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Specific ID:

```
<?php 
$desired_cat_id = 1234;
foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : 
if($cat->term_id == $desired_cat_id) :
?>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
<?php 
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Hope that helps!